# image from xml in as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm very new to as3 so excuse me if i'm not using the correct terms. I have an xml file that i periodically update with twitter info. I'm able to get my dynamic text from the xml file loaded fine, but i don't know how to get the image loaded and onto the stage. The xml has the image file name listed. The pic is save to C:\twitter. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;

var xmlData:XML = new XML();
var theURL_ur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("streamcontrol.xml");
var loader_ul:URLLoader = new URLLoader(theURL_ur);
loader_ul.addEventListener("complete", fileLoaded);

function fileLoaded(e:Event):void
{
xmlData = XML(loader_ul.data);
picFileName.load = xmlData.twitter.picFileName;
username.text = xmlData.twitter.username;
twittertext.text = xmlData.twitter.text;

}
```

Here is the XML file

```
!DOCTYPE StreamControl>
<items>
 <timestamp>1402974867</timestamp>
 <Ap1>Bankai213</Ap1>
 <Ap2>PrinceMurphy</Ap2>
 <Bp1>D3v</Bp1>
 <Bp2>GPTV|Iori Sei / Reiji</Bp2>
 <Cp1>Hamill</Cp1>
 <Cp2>Stonehead</Cp2>
 <Dp1>Eat My Jolly Hotdog</Dp1>
 <Dp2>Ricardo Fellini</Dp2>
 <Ep1>JAV|Krimpai</Ep1>
 <Ep2>HashTag2dLifeTNK1</Ep2>
 <Fp1>JAV|Krimpai</Fp1>
 <Fp2>BTAS|Conroy</Fp2>
 <Gp1>Mark Hamill</Gp1>
 <Gp2>KR|Swordy</Gp2>
 <cTitle1>Current Topic</cTitle1>
 <cTitle2>Spurs/Heat</cTitle2>
 <mText1></mText1>
 <mText2></mText2>
 <mText3></mText3>
 <mText5></mText5>
 <pCountry1>PH</pCountry1>
 <pCountry2>US</pCountry2>
 <pName1>Dru</pName1>
 <pName2>PrinceMurphy</pName2>
 <pScore1>0</pScore1>
 <pScore2>0</pScore2>
<twitter>
 <username>mashable</username>
 <twittername>Mashable</twittername>
 <text>Listen to these 23 songs to feed your rebellious side. 
#MusicMonday        http://t.co/xl4wPDHIx1 http://t.co/4YRSdqyzYR</text>
 <created>Tue Jun 17 03:01:29 +0000 2014</created>
 <picFileName>5c348fee8afbcefa1978004a864a51ce.png</picFileName>
</twitter>
<game>Vampire Savior</game>
</items>
```

Comment: Well, loading an image from `C:\twitter` is a bad idea. Instead place the image where your SWF gets output (probably the same folder as the FLA file). Rather than loading a `C:\...` url you just load a relative URL. With that said, look here to figure out how to load an image and add it to the stage http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loader/

Comment: Ok,so im able to get the image to load. However, the relative url changes, since the image name changes. How do i get it to load the image name that's listed in the xml? Also how can i manipulate that image on the stage?

Comment: Well, where are all these images located? I would assume you'd just reference it via `xmlData.twitter.picFileName`

Comment: The image now saves to the location of the .fla. I added a blank Movie clip with the instance name picFileName. I used load.xmlData.twitter.picFileName. I get no errors, but the pic does not display.

Comment: code above has been edited with the code im currently using.

Comment: Review and try this: http://pastie.org/9309483

Comment: Thanks. That works! How can i manipulate the size of the pic?

Comment: I'd imagine you want to resize the image proportionally. All this can be found on the internet through a basic search. Try this: http://snipplr.com/view/29015/as3-resize-with-ratio/ You would use it like `var newDimensions:Object = resize(800,600,320,200);` then use the `newDimensions` object to set the size on your image.